# Changing twitter bootstrap validation states of a control group in grails

Tags: validation, twitter-bootstrap, grails

so I have a gsp with a form, and I am trying to use twitter validation states when validating the form fields. I am using a grails command object for validation. The problem is that grails provides a way to add the "error" class onto a control group if a field from the command object has errors using " ${hasErrors(bean:validationCommand, field:'start', 'error')}" . This adds the error tag if the field "start" has validation errors. This works fine, up to a point. So the start field turns red on validation error. But I want it to turn green on a validation success also! which is not happening.

So, here is the start form field :

```
 <div 
class="control-group ${hasErrors(bean:validationCommand, field:'start', 'error')}">
                    <label class="control-label" for="start">Starting Tag</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <g:textField name="start"
                            value="${fieldValue(bean:validationCommand,field:'start')}"
                            class="input-medium " />
                        <g:hasErrors bean="${validationCommand}" field="start">
                            <ul>
                                <span class="help-inline"> <g:renderErrors
                                        bean="${validationCommand}" field="start" as="list" />
                                </span>
                            </ul>
                        </g:hasErrors>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

One way I could think of setting this up is by using a test to see if the field has errors and setting a variable (say startState) to success or error and then using ${startState} class in the div.

```
<g:if test="${ hasErrors(bean:validationCommand, field:'start') }">
                    <g:set var="startState" value="error"/>
                </g:if>
                <g:else>
                    <g:set var="startState" value="success"/>
                </g:else>
                </g:if>
                <div
                    class="control-group ${startState}">
                    <--same gsp as above-->
```

What this does is that it the field is green from the beginning (even when nothing is entered in the text field) and then turns red on error, or stays green.

My last attempt to make this work involved another if test to see whether the field is set using

```
<g:if test="${fieldValue(bean:validationCommand,field:'start') != null }">
```

This doesnt affect the outcome from the second attempt.

So the question is , how can i dynamically add the success class to a div tag based on the validation of the input field.

EDIT :

The controller is shown below :

```
class ValidationController {

def index() {
}

def validate(ValidationCommand cmd) {
    if (cmd.hasErrors()) {
        render view: 'index', model: [validationCommand: cmd]
    } else {
        try {
            SourceLocation repo = SourceLocation.findById(cmd.repo)
            def parentJira = cmd.issueService.findIssue(cmd.jira)

            Collection<IssueViewModel> issues = cmd.issueService.listIssuesForParent(cmd.jira)
            Collection<SourceCommitViewModel> commits = cmd.sourceRepositoryService.listCommits(repo.project, repo.slug, cmd.start, cmd.end)

            def (valid, missing_linked_issues, missing_mentioned_issues, bad_commits, issues_with_filtered_commits) = cmd.validationService.validate(repo, issues, commits)
            [ParentJira: parentJira, Valid: valid, Commits: commits, Issues: issues, LinkedMissing: missing_linked_issues, MentionedMissing: missing_mentioned_issues, BadCommits: bad_commits, SourceCommitValidation: issues_with_filtered_commits]
        } catch (e) {
            log.error( "Validation Controller Error", e )
            flash.message = "validation.service.failed"
            flash.args = [e.message]
            flash.default = "Validation Service failed"
            redirect action: 'index', params: params
        }
    }
}
}
```

The command object is :

```
class ValidationCommand {

def validationService
def sourceRepositoryService
def issueService

String jira
String repo
String start
String end

static constraints = {
    jira blank: false, nullable: false, matches: "[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+", validator: existsIssueAndIsARelease
    repo blank: false, nullable: false, validator: { val, obj -> SourceLocation.findById(val) != null }
    start blank: false, nullable: false, validator: existsTag
    end blank: false, nullable: false, validator: existsTag
}
}
```

Comment: Show your controller with all the actions for this

Comment: Added the controller and the command object, but this is a gsp question right? How do i add the success/error class or none conditionally based on whether a bean has errors or has succeeded validation?

Answer (score 0):

You can look here: [Grails hasErrors method with ternary operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955589/grails-haserrors-method-with-ternary-operator), but shortly, hasErrors(bean:validationCommand, field:'start') does not behave as you expect it to (meaning - it does not return a boolean). It's intended to be used in css-class expressions. So in your case I'd create a tag for that or there is also a quick workaround (which kinda looks ugly, so I don't really recommend it):

    `<g:if test="${ hasErrors(bean:validationCommand, field:'start', 'true') } == 'true'">
        <g:set var="startState" value="error"/>
    </g:if>
    <g:else>
        <g:set var="startState" value="success"/>
    </g:else>
    <div class="control-group ${startState}">`